# How to logout from spotify [Authentication Library] [spotify-android-auth-1.0]

Tags: android, authentication, spotify

we are using the Spotify Authentication Library (spotify-auth:1.0.0-beta11). The library contains a method to logout user from the account.

```
AuthenticationClient.logout(context);
```

After updating to latest version of the SDK (spotify-android-auth-1.0) this method is gone and the [Authentication Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/android-sdk-authentication-guide/#disqus_thread) says that we can use

> AuthenticationClient#clearCookies

But this method is also unavailable in the SDK. It doesn't even documented in the [Android SDK API References](https://spotify.github.io/android-auth/)

The question is how we can logout from the spotify now? Is there a chance to bring back the logout() method to the SDK?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yup did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you're using the Spotify application to perform the login (if you call AuthenticationClient.openLoginActivity) the only way I am aware of is if the user logs out from the Spotify application itself and you cant really control much.. However, if you're using the WebView for authentication, one possible way would be to clear Webview's cookies, theoretically this should work although I haven't tested myself.